# Clean master branch but also detailed record of intermediary commits

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, git-log

**Goal**: keep a clean history of master, whilst also keeping the intermediary commits.

**For instance**, let's start with a master branch:

```
M1 --- M2 --- M3
              ^                  
              master
```

I work on a feature/bug/whatever on a new branch:

```
M1 --- M2 --- M3
              ^  \
              |   \- F1 --- F2 -- F3
              |                   ^
              master              feature
```

And when I merge into master, I want `M3` to be the parent, but also keep the "iterations" you took to reach from `M3` to the new commit. This can be done with `merge --no-ff`:

```
M1 --- M2 --- M3 ----------------------- M4
                 \                    /  ^
                  \- F1 --- F2 -- F3-/   master
                                  ^
                                 feature
```

Which is almost what I had in mind. The problem I have is that for git, as far as I can tell, both `M3` and `F3` are "equal" parents of `M4`, now both part of branch `master`.

**What I want** is to be able the show (with `git log`) the master branch without the feature branch (`F1-F3`) to have a cleaner view over the branch. ideally this would be default. But also be able to show the `F1` `F3` commits to view the more "detailed" history when needed.

Is there a way to have this, or something close to this in `git`?

Comment: As Alejandro C. said, use `--first-parent` to follow only first parent links. Note that this requires a bit of discipline when merging (the `--no-ff` that you have already noted, and avoiding the typical `git pull` as it makes other people's commits look like feature branches that were merged in as second parents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
git log --first-parent master
```

To quote the manual

> Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit. This option can give a better overview when viewing the evolution of a particular topic branch, because merges into a topic branch tend to be only about adjusting to updated upstream from time to time, and this option allows you to ignore the individual commits brought in to your history by such a merge.