# Git change branch historically

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-rebase, git-commit

When I look at my repository network on https://github.com/user/repo/network, the graph of my repo looks like this:

**Shown:**

```
       ------------ A2 (branch a)
      |
A0 -- A1 -- B0 (branch b)
      |
       ------------------ C0 -- C1 (branch c)
```

Though the graph structure is correct, it looks like branch a originated from branch b. This effect is extra strong because [A0-A1-B0] all have the same color whereas [A2] is colored differently and so is [C0-C1].

**Expected:**

```
       ----- B0 (branch b)
      |
A0 -- A1 ---------- A2 (branch a)
      |
       ------------------ C0 -- C1 (branch c)
```

I am wondering if this is just a displaying "issue" or wether or not this is somehow actually encoded into the git history.

I did some rebasing (private repo) to make the graph look nicer when I accidentally committed to the wrong branch.

Is there a way to assign A0 and A1 to branch a historically to make the graph look like expected? Or should I just not worry about this issue?

Comment: `A0` and `A1` are part of all 3 branches. It is just a display issue. I wouldn't worry about it. Slightly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435485/clean-master-branch-but-also-detailed-record-of-intermediary-commits

Comment: Thank, I suspected that because when I click on the commit it indeed shows that they are part of all 3 branches. That link looks useful, though it does indeed seem quite cumbersome to go into changing the --first-parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue.

In `git`, there is no notion of "this is a root branch" vs "this is a fork", `branch a`, `branch b` and `branch c` are stored in completely symmetrical ways.

The order in which the branches are drawn (blind guess : alphabetical order) and the fact that the common history is on the same horizontal line as `branch b` (blind guess : the common history was drawn in the middle) relies purely on the drawing library, and does not reflect any information stored in the repo.